# Exact Target query activity in Automation studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I am new to Exact Target and i seek some help from the peoples here.And I have one requirement regarding journey builder and I don't know how to start.It will be very very helpful for me if someone helps me out how to start this and my requirement is,

> 1. A new data will be pushed to DataExtension from external system.
> 2. Then I need to check that DataExtension based on the date everyday whether the new data is available in any other Data extension (including the DE of Master Account).
> 3. If they exist I should not allow them to journey and if they don't exist i should allow them into journey.
>      This is my requirement and i guess its not possible to do in journey builder but it can be done through Automation studio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean exactly by "*...check that DataExtension based on the date everyday whether the new data is available in any other Data extension*" however I assume you are referring to checking to see if records that appear in one Data Extension exist in others. Assuming this is correct, you could write a query to **update** these distinct records to a different Data Extension. So, any new records are updated in the target DE.

Then, after the Query Activity all you would need is a Fire Event Activity. This Fire Event Activity would use the target DE from the previous query as your Event Source DE (in the Journey Builder Event).

From reviewing your third step, it appears that you only want **new** records to enter the Journey, and that's exactly what will happen. When new records are added to the Event Source and the Event is fired, a "high watermark" is added to the last record in the DE, so the next time the Automation runs, only records added since the last time the Automation will run will enter the Interaction.

On a related note, you can also ensure that records only enter a journey once. In the [March 2016 release](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/release_notes/march_2016_release/#automation) there is a new 'No re-entry' Contact Entry mode, which will only allow a Contact to enter any version of an Interaction once.

Comment: Hi Eliot thanks for your comment it was very helpful man.And i don't understand what you mean on this line "Assuming this is correct, you could write a query to update these distinct records to a different Data Extension. So, any new records are updated in the target DE"

Comment: Hello Manoj, this refers to my comment on step 2 of your question. In order to provide further detail, you need to describe what the relationships are in your Data Extensions so I can provide further detail on what the query would look like.

Comment: Hi @elliot, do you have some documentation on this "high watermark"? I think my issue is regarding this..